# Executar 2 `SUM` em um `UPDATE`

Tags: mysql

Bom estou tentando fazer o `SUM` de dois campos diferente e dar um `UPDATE` em uma outra tabela.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
 UPDATE 
        pedidos a
    SET 
        custo = (
            SELECT 
                case when SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.custo) is null then '0' else SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.custo) end  AS total
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos b
            WHERE 
                b.id_pedido = a.id
            )
        valor = (
            SELECT 
                case when SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.valor) is null then '0' else SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.valor) end  AS total
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos b
            WHERE 
                b.id_pedido = a.id
            )
    where 
        id = '2'
```

Porém o mysql me retorna um erro de sintaxe no segundo `SUM`.
Se eu fazer as query separadas elas funcionam, exemplo:

```
    UPDATE 
        pedidos a
    SET 
        custo = (
            SELECT 
                case when SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.custo) is null then '0' else SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.custo) end  AS total
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos b
            WHERE 
                b.id_pedido = a.id
            )
    where 
        id = '2'


    UPDATE 
        pedidos a
    SET 
        valor = (
            SELECT 
                case when SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.valor) is null then '0' else SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.valor) end  AS total
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos b
            WHERE 
                b.id_pedido = a.id
            )
    where 
        id = '2'
```

Bom acho que para ficar mais eficiente fica melhor eu juntar as query, é possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou uma vírgula `,`, após o fechamento dos parenteses do `select` do campo `custo`:

```
    UPDATE 
        pedidos a
    SET 
        custo = (
            SELECT 
                case when SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.custo) is null then '0' else SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.custo) end  AS total
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos b
            WHERE 
                b.id_pedido = a.id
            ),
        valor = (
            SELECT 
                case when SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.valor) is null then '0' else SUM((b.qtd - b.qtd_devolucao) * b.valor) end  AS total
            FROM 
                produtos_pedidos b
            WHERE 
                b.id_pedido = a.id
            )
    where 
        id = '2'
```

Comment: Hahahah e mesmo, obrigado.